# Using intent to sent arraylist value in android

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

Want to send ArrayList to another activity,
While using intent facing error in runtime

```
"parcel: unable to marshal value error".
```

MyCode:

```
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),SecondActitivty.class);

            Bundle extra = new Bundle();
            extra.putSerializable("objects", hotellista);

            try {
                /*Bundle bundle = new Bundle();  
                bundle.putSerializable("searchresul8t", hotellista);*/
                i.putExtra("searchrtre", extra);
                //i.putExtras(bundle);
                //i.putExtra("searchresult", hotellista);       

                startActivity(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: What Objects does your `ArrayList` contain ? ?

Comment: Does your activity implements Serializable

Comment: i used implements serializable in bean class.But now also im getting error like java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

Comment: so your bean class should implement Parceable instead of serializable.And Please post your stack trace first so that we can pinpoint the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your Class have to implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) so you can pass it from an `Activity` to another

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
           Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),SecondActitivty.class);              

            try {
                i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("YourArrayList", yourarraylist);
      // or you can try like
                  i.putStringArrayListExtra("YourArrayList", yourarraylist);

                startActivity(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: it says Parcelable encountered IOException